# Apache virtualhost with a domain

Tags: apache, dns, virtualhost

I have an apache server with a bought domain.

I want to know if it is possible to redirect some web pages... For example
I have a NextCloud Server that I want to access by www.example.com/nextcloud
And a plex server I want to access by www.example.com/plex

PD: I don't have the possibilities of subdomains like www.plex.example.com because I didn't hire it when I bought the domain

Is this possible? How do I need to configure apache virtualhost? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You mention that you want to access *by* www.example.com/nextcloud and *by* www.example.com/plex.  I will therefore take for granted that you do not want the site address to change in your client's browser.  So no redirection here.  Redirection would change the address bar value.

Then the option you want is a reverse proxy.  It will "hide" the fact that the client is being served pages by another site or application.

Assumptions:

- You have system 1 with an Apache server that responds to http://www.example.com
- You have system 2 with an application that responds to http://www.domain1.com/nextcloud.
- You have system 3 with an a plex application that reponds to http://www.domain2.com/plex

Therefore on system 1, in the configuration file for your Apache (most probably httpd.conf), you will:

- load the proxy modules
- add these lines in your `<VirtualHost>`:

  ```
  <VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName www.example.com
      ServerAlias example.com

      [... SOME OTHER CONFIG ...]

      ProxyPass "/nextcloud" "http://www.domain1.com/nextcloud"
      ProxyPassReverse "/nextcloud" "http://www.domain1.com/nextcloud"

      ProxyPass "/plex "http://www.domain2.com/plex"
      ProxyPassReverse "/plex" "http://www.domain2.com/plex"

      [... SOME OTHER CONFIG ...]
  </VirtualHost>
  ```

Now domain1.com and domain2.com can be IP addresses, but using dns is so much better for flexibility.  Adjust this sample as required.

Complete mod_proxy documentation: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html